# Best practices with Forms Authentication and Routing?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, routes

My site (WebForms, C# 4.0) is using Forms Auth and by default requires login:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I allow unauthenticated access to the public folder (http://siteurl.com/member/public):

```
<location path="member/public">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

It all works fine. Then, I added a route (RouteTable.MapPageRoute(...)), so that

```
http://siteurl.com/member/public/view.aspx?username=someusername
```

can be accessed by going to:

```
http://siteurl.com/member/view/someusername
```

My problem is - now I also need to add member/view location to web.config to allow unauth access to it, so I have to have two entries for technically the same location:

```
<location path="member/public"> <!-- physical location -->
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>

<location path="member/view"> <!-- route -->
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

I will have a bunch of those routes to pages in member/public folder, so looks like I'd have to list each of them in web.config, and it doesn't sound right...

Is there any way to tell ASP.NET to automatically apply physical path auth rules to the routing so that I woudl only need to specify unauth access to member/public and all routes to the location would automatically gain access?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? - I have the same problem (except worse as there is a dynamic key in my routing structure, so I'd need a `location path`... for each URL nearly).

Comment: I ended up creating a custom module that handles security - almost complete override of asp.net security